# Alteração de objeto com javascript

Tags: javascript, array, map

Minha API esta retornando um `array` com os objetos na seguinte estrutura:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "Flávio", position: "SP - Atacante"},
  {id: 2, name: "João", position: "SP - Goleiro"},
  {id: 3, name: "Fernando", position: "RJ - Zagueiro"},
  {id: 5, name: "Robert", position: "SP - Todas"},
];
```

Eu preciso pegar a última posição desse cara (objeto com `position: 'SP - Todas'`) e remover o texto SP - , deixando apenas a escrita "Todas".

Tentei da seguinte forma e funcionou (não deve ser a melhor forma, se tiverem sugestão, agradeço).

```
jogadores.map((jogador, i) => {
    if (jogador.position.includes('Todas')) {
    console.log(jogador.position.substr(4));
  };
});
```

O problema é que preciso retornar o array com este último objeto editado, mas não estou sabendo como fazer.

[Exemplo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp5xas7w/)

Comment: Queres remover o `SP` na "ultima posição" ou na que tem o texto "Todas"? no exemplo é a mesma, mas é sempre a mesma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver este problema, basta apenas utilizar a [função split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), o resultado desta operação  é um array em que:

1. na posição zero estará o valor `"SP "`
2. na posição um estará o valor `" Todas"`

Assim basta remover os espaços em branco para a posição um do array [chamando a função `trim()`].

```
const jogadores = [
    {id: 1, name: "Flávio", position: "SP - Atacante"},
    {id: 2, name: "João", position: "SP - Goleiro"},
    {id: 3, name: "Fernando", position: "RJ - Zagueiro"},
    {id: 5, name: "Robert", position: "SP - Todas"},
]

const j = jogadores.map((jogador) => {
    if (jogador.position.includes('Todas')) {
      jogador.position = jogador.position.split('-')[1].trim();
      return jogador;
    }
    return jogador;
})
```

Comment: Estás a usar o `.map` para mudar a array inicial... devias usar o retorno do `map` para gerar uma array alterada e não mudar a array inicial.

Comment: Obrigado por reportar o erro. Já corrigi.